# how to send/upload file using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

How to send/upload file information to php using jquery ajax?
info is the file  to be uploaded.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data, /* data from input file to upload it */
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
            },
            complete: function() {

            },        
            cache: false,
            success: callback,
            error: function(error) {
                alert("Some problems have occured. Please try again later: " + error);
            }
        });

<form id="product-form" action="javascript: product();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="img" />
<a href="#" class="link2" onclick="document.getElementById('product-form').submit()">Submit</a> 
</form>
```

Comment: is `info` the path? what do yo mean it's the file?

Comment: yah do i can use $_FILES or what ever data i should send to upload image

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with jQuery alone.  You need to either use a jQuery plugin such as [Uploadify](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CIUBEBYwAA&url=http://www.uploadify.com/&ei=XMSpT7edBsPv6AHdv_2nBA&usg=AFQjCNEpTOmRIaTRQ7F8JNaxa7VhKljjwQ&sig2=yrn-PhteAuvOiZhxjOaqLA) or use [HTML 5](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-ajax-file-upload/).  Please note that not all browsers support HTML 5 at this time, so jQuery Uploadify may be the better choice.