# jQuery validation plugin send file using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var dataString = $('#YourFormID').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'yourpage.php',
                data: dataString,
                success:  function() {
                    $('#YourErrorDivID').hide();
                    $('#YourSuccessDivID').html("Your Message").show();
                }
            });
        }
```

How can I send a file via this code ? with this code I cannot send a file .
BTW what is datatype : json and how do I use it in my php file if I got it from jQuery file?

Edit : I didn't ask for a code, I've tried to send a file input data with the code above and it didn't work . So I want to know how to repair this code so it will also send file input value & regular data(such as textarea etc.)

Comment: this question is crap

Comment: I ask how to send a file via jquery . I didn't find answer after a long search ..

Comment: @Dagon please check my question again .. I just ask for help . I saw a solution (here) that I can use $_POST to access my file after it send via AJAX . As you probably guess it didn't work . So, I really need help . I just want to save my file without reload the page .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only done this once, so I'm no expert, and it confused me, but I think I can answer you. Assuming you have something like this in your file:

```
var dataString = {
page_num: page
};
```

It can then be referenced like this on yourpage.php, as it was sent via post:

```
$requested_page = $_POST['page_num'];
```

JSON still confuses me, but its a way of storing data. It's a type of array usually, I believe. PHP has the functions `json_encode` and `json_decode` to allow you to use it. for example, you receive `$json` which is data in json format then you:

```
$x = json_decode($json,TRUE);
var_dump($x);
```

and that should make it into an associative array.

UPDATE:

[how to send/upload file using jquery or javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508393/how-to-send-upload-file-using-jquery-or-javascript)
According to this question, you can't upload a file with jquery. Nor do I think you should try, as some people have javascript disabled on their browsers. I use jquery for aesthetics and infinite scroll on my website, and will soon put in a pagination feature that runs if js is deactivated. Your site needs to be at least basically accessible without js.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfD51iRTAXU&list=PLE134D877783367C7&index=45
This tutorial shows the basics of file upload in html if you don't know that(though it isn't a great tutorial, I found it very helpful when I was just learning, and a good starting point).

If you've already uploaded a file using php, SQL, and html, then you can reference it with it's filename/filepath, as shown in that tutorial. So you could send the filename/filepath through jquery, and just use that on the other side if you want to use jquery to build dynamic content.

Comment: thanks for your help ! I've read about it and got confused too . now I understand it better .

Comment: Can someone help with my first question ?